# Know how much a user has paid for a product on GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

According to [Google's documentation about Android Publisher](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products#ProductPurchase), the object they send with the details about a product someone bought doesn't include the price they paid.

Is there any way to have that price? Stadia's "Purchases & Subscriptions" screen shows how much I paid for the games I bought, that of course now is cheaper. I mean, the screen doesn't show today's product's price, but the amount I paid.